# Glib — undefined reference to anything from glib?

Tags: c, glib

I have a problem with my S program.
I need to compile it with this command:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 \
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c99 -lm *.c \
    -o generator1_1
```

I have many error messages like this:

```
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/main.c:153: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_lookup'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/main.c:171: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_insert'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/main.c:172: undefined reference to `g_array_append_vals'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/main.c:179: undefined reference to `g_array_append_vals'
/tmp/ccVqEbsM.o: In function `main':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/main.c:238: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_new_full'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/main.c:239: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_new_full'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/main.c:263: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_destroy'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/main.c:264: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_destroy'
/tmp/cc2UG2Wy.o: In function `fillVFile':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/reader.c:47: undefined reference to `g_strdup'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/reader.c:51: undefined reference to `g_ptr_array_add'
/tmp/cctOiTOl.o: In function `calculRegles':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:23: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_get_values'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:48: undefined reference to `g_list_length'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:57: undefined reference to `g_list_sort'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:82: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_new'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:85: undefined reference to `g_array_new'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:110: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_lookup'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:116: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_lookup'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:121: undefined reference to `log2'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:125: undefined reference to `g_array_append_vals'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:128: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_insert'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:139: undefined reference to `g_array_sort'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:167: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_lookup'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:176: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_lookup'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:198: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_destroy'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:199: undefined reference to `g_array_free'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/regles.c:205: undefined reference to `g_list_free'
/tmp/cczRKfT8.o: In function `cstSequence1':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence1.c:19: undefined reference to `g_array_new'
/tmp/cczRKfT8.o: In function `dstSequence1':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence1.c:26: undefined reference to `g_array_free'
/tmp/cczRKfT8.o: In function `hashSeq1Fct':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence1.c:97: undefined reference to `g_str_hash'
/tmp/cczRKfT8.o: In function `eqSeq1Fct':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence1.c:113: undefined reference to `g_str_equal'
/tmp/cc7ZNuaW.o: In function `cstSequence2':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence2.c:22: undefined reference to `g_array_new'
/tmp/cc7ZNuaW.o: In function `dstSequence2':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence2.c:29: undefined reference to `g_array_free'
/tmp/cc7ZNuaW.o: In function `hashSeq2Fct':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence2.c:131: undefined reference to `g_str_hash'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence2.c:132: undefined reference to `g_str_hash'
/tmp/cc7ZNuaW.o: In function `eqSeq2Fct':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence2.c:152: undefined reference to `g_str_equal'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/sequence2.c:153: undefined reference to `g_str_equal'
/tmp/ccY2cdEJ.o: In function `foncteurRetireDoublonsSeq1':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/utils.c:29: undefined reference to `g_array_remove_index'
/tmp/ccY2cdEJ.o: In function `foncteurRetireDoublonsSeq2':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/utils.c:52: undefined reference to `g_array_remove_index'
/tmp/ccY2cdEJ.o: In function `retireDoublonsLignesSeq1':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/utils.c:66: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_get_values'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/utils.c:68: undefined reference to `g_list_foreach'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/utils.c:70: undefined reference to `g_list_free'
/tmp/ccY2cdEJ.o: In function `retireDoublonsLignesSeq2':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/utils.c:75: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_get_values'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/utils.c:77: undefined reference to `g_list_foreach'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/utils.c:79: undefined reference to `g_list_free'
/tmp/cc8GGinx.o: In function `cstVFile':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/vfile.c:15: undefined reference to `g_ptr_array_sized_new'
/tmp/cc8GGinx.o: In function `dstVFile':
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/vfile.c:26: undefined reference to `g_free'
/home/cyrine/Bureau/Seq_GLib2_1_1_Triche/vfile.c:29: undefined reference to `g_ptr_array_free'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I work with Ubuntu 12.04.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: are you sure the libraries are installed and are in your `PATH` ?

Comment: Put the library you link with *last*, after the object and source files.

Comment: Isn't there any error message about the library itself, *before* all of the specific error messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the libraries, specified by `-l`, after the 'object' files (or source files when you compile the source and link all at once).

You have:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include \
    -lglib-2.0 \
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c99 \
    -lm *.c -o generator1_1
```

You need:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include \
    -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c99 \
    *.c -lglib-2.0 -lm -o generator1_1
```

There may be a few systems where you can specify libraries at arbitrary positions in the linking command line, but 'libraries after object files' has always worked on all the systems I've ever come across.