# linking gives me "undefined reference" to for each referred function from libc.so

Tags: gcc, reference, linker, undefined, glib

These both questions did not solve my problem:
[glib-undefined-reference-to-anything-from-glib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960766/glib-undefined-reference-to-anything-from-glib)
and
[undefined-reference-to-pthread-create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253200/undefined-reference-to-pthread-create)

I am writing a personalized version of the `snprintf` function from glibc-2.21. When I want to link my `main.o` which is calling the new function `snpprintf()` then I receive dozens of `undefined reference to` errors from linker for each call/reference of a glibc-2.21 function.

This is the command:

```
ar rvs libFaFsprintf.a snpprintf.o vfpprintf.o vsnpprintf.o iovspprintf.o
gcc main.o libFaFsprintf.a -lc -o main
```

I have my object files in the library `libFafsprintf.a` - it does not matter if I provide the library or I specify each object file. The source code is compiled without any problem.
I tried also to change the order of my library and `-lc` - nothing helps.

It only works when I use the `-static` option but I do **not** want to link libc statically with the executable.

How do I have to link the program?

Comment: Could it be that your glib architecture doesn't match that of your objects?

Comment: When I link it statically then it works. This means that far all is OK.

Comment: No, when you link statically you are using a physically different library.

Comment: OK. This I did not know. My personalized version of `snprintf()` is a copy from the GNU glib-2.2 package. I link it with glib-2.0 - can this be the problem? But why it works when linked as static. How can I checked which library is used when linking statically?

Comment: To troubleshoot, 1. Use a full path to `libglib-2.x.y.so` instead of `-lglib-2.0`. 2. `nm <path-to-glib> | grep <undefined-symbol>`, what do you see?

Comment: 1) adding the full path does not change anything. in my system is only one version of libglib-2.0.so 2) When running with path-to-glib then I get `nm: /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so: no symbols`

Comment: Your glib is stripped and cannot be linked with. You need to install the development package of glib. Look at your package manager, search for packages ending in -dev or -devel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71780/discussion-between-al-bundy-and-n-m).

Comment: I think you're confusing GLib with glibc (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library).  snprintf is not in glib.

Comment: @nemequ: Yes, you are totally right! Can you tell me which library I have to provide the linker to compile it - **NOT** static.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I have to link the program?

Like this:

```
gcc main.o libFaFsprintf.a -lglib-2.0 -o main
```

Comment: as user nemequ realized, I mismatched in the 1st version of the question glib with libc. Usually I do not need to provided the standard C library for the link process